# Cannot resolve symbol for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

How come I'm getting this error when I try to declare a Fragment in XML?

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

"Cannot resolve symbol: ArticleListFragment"??

Code file name ArticleListFragment.java

```
package com.example.myapp5;

import android.app.Fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ArticleListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    }

}
```

Comment: You meed to use class=com.example.news.ArticleListFragment instead of name.

Comment: But I got this straight from Google's Android tutorials! See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html and then search for "Adding a fragment to an activity"

Comment: My bad. I see that now. You must not have your ArticleListFragment in the right spot. Make sure you have a java class named so.

Comment: I created a ArticleListFragment.java and then have created this:public class ArticleListFragment extends Fragment {

It says "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'class'
}

Comment: can you post all your code please

Comment: Code posted, this seems like a very simple thing to do, but it just won't work.  What is the point of the android:name="" used for anyways?

Comment: android:name just specifies what class your fragment is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: How the Fragment should be set up]

I don't know if this completely answers your question, but it sounds like something just isn't set up properly. I have included an example that should illustrate what your File Explorer should look like given you are running Android Studio (It will still look similar to this in Eclipse).

Now, you need to make sure everything in `android:name` looks right here, but for your package.

Answer (score 4):

You use `com.example.news.ArticleListFragment` as fully qualified class name, but the real name of your class is `com.example.myapp5.ArticleListFragment`, because you have created it in different package than the tutorial.

So you should use

```
android:name="com.example.myapp5.ArticleListFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import your fragment in the java file.